# How to activate a button by pressing a specific key on the keyboard?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hey I'm pretty new to programming and I'm wondering how to activate a button in Windows Forms by pressing a designated key, thank you.

I tried doing this:

```
    private void Form_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            btn_A.PerformClick();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

But I can't seem to get it to work. Note that I am very new to all this so apologies in advance.

Comment: I've updated the post with some additional info, sorry for being so vague

Comment: Okay, that should be more likely to get you an answer.  People here usually prefer to answer questions that show that the asker has tried something and are stumped, over questions that don't show effort on the asker's end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe easier. Create a KeyPress-Event of the Form and test for the specific key:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //Test for Specific Key
        if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            //Do Stuff like:
            button1.Enabled = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do I run this method so It's always present?

Comment: Do you mean that it is always checking ? @klemenhe

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `KeyPreview` to `true`?

Comment: Sorry, how do I do that?

Comment: It is a property of `Form`. You can either use the `Properties` window for your form in the designer, or add this line in the `Form1()` constructor : `KeyPreview = true;`.